# newInstance vs new in jdk-9/jdk-8 and jmh

Tags: java, performance, java-8, jmh, java-9

I've seen a lot of threads here that compare and try to answer which is faster: `newInstance` or `new operator`.

Looking at the source code, it would seem that `newInstance` should be **much slower**, I mean it does so many security checks and uses reflection. And I've decided to measure, first running jdk-8. Here is the code using `jmh`.

```
@BenchmarkMode(value = { Mode.AverageTime, Mode.SingleShotTime })
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 2, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)   
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 2, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)    
@State(Scope.Benchmark) 
public class TestNewObject {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {

        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder().include(TestNewObject.class.getSimpleName()).build();
        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

    @Fork(1)
    @Benchmark
    public Something newOperator() {
       return new Something();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Fork(1)
    @Benchmark
    public Something newInstance() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
         return Something.class.newInstance();
    }

    static class Something {

    } 
}
```

I don't think there are big surprises here (JIT does a lot of optimizations that make this difference not *that big*):

```
Benchmark                  Mode  Cnt      Score      Error  Units
TestNewObject.newInstance  avgt    5      7.762 ±    0.745  ns/op
TestNewObject.newOperator  avgt    5      4.714 ±    1.480  ns/op
TestNewObject.newInstance    ss    5  10666.200 ± 4261.855  ns/op
TestNewObject.newOperator    ss    5   1522.800 ± 2558.524  ns/op
```

The difference for the hot code would be around **2x** and much worse for single shot time.

Now I switch to jdk-9 (build 157 in case it matters) and run the same code.
And the results:

```
 Benchmark                  Mode  Cnt      Score      Error  Units
 TestNewObject.newInstance  avgt    5    314.307 ±   55.054  ns/op
 TestNewObject.newOperator  avgt    5      4.602 ±    1.084  ns/op
 TestNewObject.newInstance    ss    5  10798.400 ± 5090.458  ns/op
 TestNewObject.newOperator    ss    5   3269.800 ± 4545.827  ns/op
```

That's a **whooping 50x** difference in hot code. I'm using latest jmh version (1.19.SNAPSHOT).

After adding one more method to the test:

```
@Fork(1)
@Benchmark
public Something newInstanceJDK9() throws Exception {
    return Something.class.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
}
```

Here are the overall results n jdk-9:

```
TestNewObject.newInstance      avgt    5    308.342 ±   107.563  ns/op
TestNewObject.newInstanceJDK9  avgt    5     50.659 ±     7.964  ns/op
TestNewObject.newOperator      avgt    5      4.554 ±     0.616  ns/op
```

Can someone shed some light on *why there is such a big difference*?

Comment: Are you using a JDK9 build with jigsaw?

Comment: @JornVernee not sure it matters, but the answer is no - I am not.

Comment: It would matter, since there would be a number of additional access checks for the module the system, that the JIT might not know how to handle nicely yet.

Comment: @JornVernee almost everything jigsaw-wise is in the non-jigsaw build anyway as far as I know. But yes, that is the only thing that come to my mind also for the slower part in jdk-9.

Comment: `Class.newInstance()` is deprecated in Java 9. The performance of the recommended alternative, `clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()` would be interesting…

Comment: @Holger good point, added. The diff is still **10x**, better, but far from **2x**...

Comment: Can you make another test, now with a non-`public` (default access) constructor in `Something`?

Comment: @Holger just did - the results are *almost* the same as with the *public* constructor.

Comment: You could cache the `Constructor` instance in a static final field instead of using `Something.class.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()`. You could also try a methodhandle for the constructor and caching that. handles move the access checks to creation time instead of call time, so they should be much faster

Comment: There is no point in speculating about the differences unless you have perfasm profiles for both benchmarks.

Comment: Once you do that profiling exercise, try with `-XX:-TieredCompilation` ;)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**First of all, the problem has nothing to do with the module system (directly).**

I noticed that even with JDK 9 the first warmup iteration of `newInstance` was as fast as with JDK 8.

```
# Fork: 1 of 1
# Warmup Iteration   1: 10,578 ns/op    <-- Fast!
# Warmup Iteration   2: 246,426 ns/op
# Warmup Iteration   3: 242,347 ns/op
```

This means something has broken in JIT compilation.
`-XX:+PrintCompilation` confirmed that the benchmark was recompiled after the first iteration:

```
10,762 ns/op
# Warmup Iteration   2:    1541  689   !   3       java.lang.Class::newInstance (160 bytes)   made not entrant
   1548  692 %     4       bench.generated.NewInstance_newInstance_jmhTest::newInstance_avgt_jmhStub @ 13 (56 bytes)
   1552  693       4       bench.generated.NewInstance_newInstance_jmhTest::newInstance_avgt_jmhStub (56 bytes)
   1555  662       3       bench.generated.NewInstance_newInstance_jmhTest::newInstance_avgt_jmhStub (56 bytes)   made not entrant
248,023 ns/op
```

Then `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintInlining` pointed to the inlining problem:

```
1577  667 %     4       bench.generated.NewInstance_newInstance_jmhTest::newInstance_avgt_jmhStub @ 13 (56 bytes)
                           @ 17   bench.NewInstance::newInstance (6 bytes)   inline (hot)
            !                @ 2   java.lang.Class::newInstance (160 bytes)   already compiled into a big method
```

**"already compiled into a big method"** message means that the compiler has failed to inline `Class.newInstance` call because the compiled size of the callee is larger than `InlineSmallCode` value (which is 2000 by default).

When I reran the benchmark with `-XX:InlineSmallCode=2500`, it became fast again.

```
Benchmark                Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
NewInstance.newInstance  avgt    5  8,847 ± 0,080  ns/op
NewInstance.operatorNew  avgt    5  5,042 ± 0,177  ns/op
```

You know, JDK 9 now has **G1 as the default GC**. If I fall back to Parallel GC, the benchmark will also be fast even with the default `InlineSmallCode`.

Rerun JDK 9 benchmark with `-XX:+UseParallelGC`:

```
Benchmark                Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
NewInstance.newInstance  avgt    5  8,728 ± 0,143  ns/op
NewInstance.operatorNew  avgt    5  4,822 ± 0,096  ns/op
```

G1 requires to put some barriers whenever an object store happens, that's why the compiled code becomes a bit larger, so that `Class.newInstance` exceeds the default `InlineSmallCode` limit. Another reason why compiled `Class.newInstance` has become larger is that the reflection code had been slightly rewritten in JDK 9.

> **TL;DR** JIT has failed to inline `Class.newInstance`, because `InlineSmallCode` limit has been exceeded. The compiled version of `Class.newInstance` has become larger due to changes in reflection code in JDK 9 and because the default GC has been changed to G1.

Comment: Isn't this a big problem for reflection-heavy frameworks like Spring? Maybe this is worth a report so that the method can be made smaller (e.g. by extracting some code into a separate methods).

Comment: @KirillRakhman This should not be an issue since in the real life scenarios `newInstance` is unlikely to be inlined anyway. I can't imagine a reasonable case when the *same* constructor is called *many times* at the *same* place via reflection. In the original question the performance gain is seen only because JIT adapts to calling the specific method.

Comment: great explanation, even has a tldr!

Answer (score 4):

The implementation of `Class.newInstance()` is mostly identical, except the following part:

Java 8:

```
Constructor<T> tmpConstructor = cachedConstructor;
// Security check (same as in java.lang.reflect.Constructor)
int modifiers = tmpConstructor.getModifiers();
if (!Reflection.quickCheckMemberAccess(this, modifiers)) {
    Class<?> caller = Reflection.getCallerClass();
    if (newInstanceCallerCache != caller) {
        Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(caller, this, null, modifiers);
        newInstanceCallerCache = caller;
    }
}
```

Java 9

```
Constructor<T> tmpConstructor = cachedConstructor;
// Security check (same as in java.lang.reflect.Constructor)
Class<?> caller = Reflection.getCallerClass();
if (newInstanceCallerCache != caller) {
    int modifiers = tmpConstructor.getModifiers();
    Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(caller, this, null, modifiers);
    newInstanceCallerCache = caller;
}
```

As you can see, Java 8 had a `quickCheckMemberAccess` which allowed to bypass the expensive operations, like `Reflection.getCallerClass()`. This quick check has been removed, I’d guess, because it wasn’t compatible with the new module access rules.

But there’s more to it. The JVM might optimize reflective instantiations with a predictable type and `Something.class.newInstance()` refers to a perfectly predictable type. This optimization might have become less effective. There are several possible reasons:

- the new module access rules complicate the process
- since `Class.newInstance()` has been deprecated, some support has been deliberately removed (seems unlikely to me)
- due to the changed implementation code shown above, HotSpot fails to recognize certain code patterns that trigger the optimizations